# Azure Function deployed using FTP, how to fix non-existence docker container issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am in development phrase, and I am trying out Azure Function, with the following settings:

- Linux
- Premium Plan,
- NodeJS 12
- Deploy using FTP

What I have done:

1. I have deployed a sample `Durable Functions HTTP Starter` as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode#client-function-http-starter
2. And deployed my code to the `xxxxxxxxxxx.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net` under `/site/wwwroot`
3. And I received the following Error in `LogFiles/2020_06_10_xxxx_docker.log`:

```
2020-06-10T01:05:51.825Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
2020-06-10T01:05:51.845Z INFO  - Stopping site XXXXXXXXXX because it failed during startup.
2020-06-10T01:09:59.152Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node8-appservice-stage6
2020-06-10T01:10:00.049Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node8-appservice-stage6 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by \"3.0-node8-appservice-stage6\" is not found"}
```

4. Upon inspection, this `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node8-appservice-stage6` docker image didn't exists, so it failed.

My question is, **how to instruct Azure Function to use a valid docker image instead of a non-existing one**? Or if any step above I done wrong so result in this issue? Thanks

Comment: When you use the code type, the built-in images are default and you cannot change them. Unless you use the custom image. And in my test, the NodeJS 12 uses the image `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node12-appservice-stage5` and does not fail to pull.

Comment: To my knowledge, I have not touch any of custom image, nor do my colleages. Anyway I fix this by removing Azure function and recreating it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely removing the Azure Function and creating a new one fix this issue.